vscodium python multiline comment how to use # instead of docstring?
Linux Debian 12, wondering how to replace the behavior of vscodium that if I select multiple lines and want to get them as comment it add a docstring instead adding an hashtag to eachline.
Doctring need right indentation, hashtag is preferable for me.
I've tried the following:
keybindings.json: File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON).
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+[Comma]",
        "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorLangId == 'python' && editorTextFocus"
    }
]

in settings.json:
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": false,
    "python.autoComplete.addDocstring": false
  },

But this is still giving me docstring instead of #.
Any advice is appreciated.
